# Jumping up quicker? (Paper Mario style jump)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, gravity

So, [Paper Marios jump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNSoR.gif) takes 8 frames go reach the max jump height and 12 frames to get back to the ground. This is pretty unusual, any idea how to jump up that quick with a rigidbody?

I tried to AddForce when rigidbody.velocity.y > 0, but that didn't work out.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
        //Jump when pressing button and on ground
        //jumpForce is a public float variable

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
    {
        theRB.velocity += new Vector3(0, jumpForce, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe a better question for https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Take a look at this video from YouTube Channel Brackeys [FIRST PERSON MOVEMENT in Unity - FPS Controller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QajrabyTJc) Here you'll find your answer

Answer (score 0):

If Without rigidbody , use s = vt+1/2gt^2 , you can chagne Time.deltaTime when go up
like this:

```
public class BCDE : MonoBehaviour
{
    float v = 10;
    float g = -9.8f;
    float t = 0;
    bool go;

    [EasyButtons.Button]
    public void GO()
    {
        go = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (go)
        {
            if (v * t >= (1f / 2f * g * t * t))
            {
                t += Time.deltaTime * 1.5f ;// 12 frame / 8 frame = 1.5 ( quick 1.5 times
            }
            else
            {
                t += Time.deltaTime;
            }

            float s = v * t + (1f / 2f * g * t * t);
            if(s <= 0)
            {
                go = false;
                transform.position = Vector3.zero;
                t = 0;
                return;
            }

            transform.position = new Vector3(0, s, 0);
        }
    }
}
```